# Why is 'None' in the output?

Tags: python, list

I have a problem with this.

```
ClassA1=[7.8,5.6,8.7,8.9,9,9.5]
ClassA2=[6.0,6.5,9.3,9.2,7.5]
choice=int((input("Press 1 if you want to sort the scoreboard in ascending order.\n. Press 2 if you want to sort the scoreboard in descending order."))
total = lopA1+lopA2 
if choice == 1:
  print(total.sort())
elif choice == 2:
  print(total.sort(reverse=True))
```

After run I enter 1 or 2

```
None
```

Comment: `total.sort()` sorts the list in-place and returns None. You want `total.sort()` and then `print(total)`

Comment: @PaulHankin or possibly `sorted(total)`, which does return sorted copy of a list.

Answer (score 0):

These are signatures of list.sort function `sort(*, key: None = ..., reverse: bool = ...) -> None` & `sort(*, key: (Any) -> SupportsRichComparison, reverse: bool = ...) -> None`. It only sort the list in place (no returns). This should work instead:

```py
ClassA1 = [7.8, 5.6, 8.7, 8.9, 9, 9.5]
ClassA2 = [6.0, 6.5, 9.3, 9.2, 7.5]
choice = int(
    input(
        "Press 1 if you want to sort the scoreboard in ascending order.\n. Press 2 if you want to sort the scoreboard in descending order."
    ))
total = ClassA1 + ClassA2
if choice == 1:
    total.sort()
elif choice == 2:
    total.sort(reverse=True)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of `sort` function is always `None`, because `sort` alter the list in-place.

You can find this in a quick Google search looking for the documentation of search function in Python.

I assume you want to do this:

```
if choice == 1:
  total.sort()
  print(total)
elif choice == 2:
  total.sort(reverse=True)
  print(total)
```